# SwitchPreference Callback behaviour change in lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, preferences, android-5.1.1-lollipop

[image]

In our project we are using SwitchPreference similar to wifi settings.user can toggle value by clicking on toggle button and user can see more options by clicking on title.

But this is not working in lollipop. I can see some behaviour change in lollipop.

In kitkat:

When user taps on toggle button, **onPreferenceChanged** callback is called and when user taps on title, **onPreferenceClicked** is called.

In lollipop:
you tap on toggle button or title **onPreferenceClicked** is called always and after that **onPreferenceChanged** is called.
How can I get same behaviour in lollipop? This behaviour is breaking our functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter same issue and I found this : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=172425

After some try, I found how to implement this workaround that work on my case :

```
public class MySwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference {

/**
 * Construct a new SwitchPreference with the given style options.
 *
 * @param context The Context that will style this preference
 * @param attrs Style attributes that differ from the default
 * @param defStyle Theme attribute defining the default style options
 */
public MySwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Construct a new SwitchPreference with the given style options.
 *
 * @param context The Context that will style this preference
 * @param attrs Style attributes that differ from the default
 */
public MySwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * Construct a new SwitchPreference with default style options.
 *
 * @param context The Context that will style this preference
 */
public MySwitchPreference(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup= (ViewGroup)view;
    setSwitchClickable(viewGroup);
    super.onBindView(view);
}

private void setSwitchClickable(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
      if (null == viewGroup) {
      return;
  }

  int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
  for(int n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
      View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(n);
      if(childView instanceof Switch) {
          final Switch switchView = (Switch) childView;
          switchView.setClickable(true);
          return;
      } else if (childView instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup childGroup = (ViewGroup)childView;
        setSwitchClickable(childGroup);
      }
  }

}
```

Then you just have to use your own "MySwitchPreference" into SwitchPreference directly.

Comment: don't know why but setClickable didn't work for me. Is it working for you? I have added my workaround that i have used.

Comment: Apparently yes, the code I put there solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I have created custom SwitchPreference class

```
public class CustomSwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference {
public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
 @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        View view =  super.onCreateView(parent);
 LinearLayout switchView =  (LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(2);
switchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final boolean newValue = !isChecked();
                if (callChangeListener(newValue)) {
                    setChecked(newValue);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

It looks dirty but working for me.