# Android 5.x SwitchPreference is not behaving the same as in Android 4.x

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, switchpreference

I have a code using `SwitchPreference` that used to work with Android 4.x however it no longer works since I updated my device to Android 5.0.1.

I have a simple `SwitchPreference` which displays a title on the left and an ON/OFF switch on the right.

```
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="myPref"            
        android:selectable="true"
        android:title="Title" 
        android:fragment="com.myApp.DeviceMonitorPrefsActivity"            
        android:switchTextOn="ON"
        android:switchTextOff="OFF"/>
```

On the PreferenceActivity, I overrode `onPreferenceTreeClick()` to perform an Action (launching a setup Activity in my case) when I click on the title of this `SwitchPreference` control.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) 
    {
        if(preference instanceof SwitchPreference){
            // My Action
        }
    }
```

With Android 4.4.4, this Action used to be executed only when I pressed to the left of this control (title), but not when I changed the switch state.

Now with Android 5.0.1, the onPreferenceTreeClick() is called even when I change the switch state, and I didn't find a way to differentiate the two cases.

Is it a bug in Android 5.0.1 or is there a way to make this work cleanly?

Comment: Look like similar issue as this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906487/switchpreference-callback-behaviour-change-in-lollipop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workaround found here seems to work : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=172425

Here's my implementation that work on my case :

```
public class MySwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference {

/**
 * Construct a new SwitchPreference with the given style options.
 *
 * @param context The Context that will style this preference
 * @param attrs Style attributes that differ from the default
 * @param defStyle Theme attribute defining the default style options
 */
public MySwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Construct a new SwitchPreference with the given style options.
 *
 * @param context The Context that will style this preference
 * @param attrs Style attributes that differ from the default
 */
public MySwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * Construct a new SwitchPreference with default style options.
 *
 * @param context The Context that will style this preference
 */
public MySwitchPreference(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup= (ViewGroup)view;
    setSwitchClickable(viewGroup);
    super.onBindView(view);
}

private void setSwitchClickable(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
      if (null == viewGroup) {
      return;
  }

  int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
  for(int n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
      View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(n);
      if(childView instanceof Switch) {
          final Switch switchView = (Switch) childView;
          switchView.setClickable(true);
          return;
      } else if (childView instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup childGroup = (ViewGroup)childView;
        setSwitchClickable(childGroup);
      }
  }

}
```

Then you just have to use your own "MySwitchPreference" into SwitchPreference directly.